# catkin_make, CMake Error on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instructions in the link down below to install ROS Jade on a Raspberry Pi 2 running ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
[link text](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/UbuntuARM)
However, after setting up a catkin workspace and tried to run catkin_make, I got the following messages

> CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found. Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.

The problem is, I already have cmake installed, when I run `cmake --version`, I got

> cmake version 2.8.12.2

Any idea how to solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222332/catkin_make,-cmake-error-on-raspberry-pi-2/) by [owenqyzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25303/owenqyzhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered the same problem but solved it when I ran the following command.

sudo apt-get install build-essential -y

---

Originally posted by [KCL](https://answers.ros.org/users/25834/kcl/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0